# Lua How to reformat a date?

Tags: string, date, lua, format

I am currently retrieving a date in the format of 2020-09-23T09:03:46.242Z (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ) and I am trying to convert it into Wed Sep 23 09:03:46 2020. Struggling with the string manipulations, does anyone have any ideas?
Essentially my goal is to be able to perform os.time() on the date, but im aware I may need to do some reformatting beforehand.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks, Scott.

Comment: Do you want date validation?

Answer (score 1):

```
local s = '2020-09-23T09:03:46.242Z'
local t = {}
t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec =
   assert(s:match'^(%d+)%-(%d+)%-(%d+)T(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)')
print(os.date('%c', os.time(t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
local function convert (s)
    local source_format = '(%d%d%d%d)-(%d%d)-(%d%d)T(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d)%.'
    local year, month, day, hour, min, sec = string.match( s, source_format )
    local unix_time = os.time {
        year    = tonumber(year),
        month   = tonumber(month),
        day     = tonumber(day),
        hour    = tonumber(hour),
        min     = tonumber(min),
        sec     = tonumber(sec)
    }
    local target_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
    return os.date( target_format, unix_time )
end
```